# Swift syntax - linkUserInBackground

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm running Swift 1.2 and need help with the syntax declaration for `linkUserInBackground()`

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()
PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, {(succeeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if succeeded {
        println("Working")
    }
})
```

Error: "Missing argument for parameter 'accessToken' in call

I checked the documentation (there barely is any) and don't know what accessToken is. Any pointers?

Comment: So you have all closing braces/parentheses?

Comment: My bad. Forgot to include the closing braces/parentheses. But the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html). There are six `linkUserInBackground` functions, and all of them take more parameters than what you are providing:

1. Two functions require read permissions (one with a completion block, one without)
2. Two functions require write permissions (one with a completion block, one without)
3. Two functions require an access token (one with a completion block, one without)

You will have to decide which of the three functions with completion blocks is appropriate for your use case. If you don't have a access token, I would guess the one with read permissions, which are usually the basic "access to profile picture, email address, etc." permissions that Facebook asks for first. It might look something like this:

```
PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, withPermissions: ["email"], block: {
    success, error in
    if success {
        println("Working")
    }
})
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. 
Error: "Cannot invoke 'linkUserInBackground' with an argument list of type '(PFUser?, withPermissions: [String], block: ( _ . _ ) -> _ )'

Comment: It looks like the user cannot be optional. You can wrap that whole thing in an `if let` or just do `user!` if you are sure the user will never be `nil`.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still giving the same error. I tried both with the keyword "block" and without it.

Comment: To confirm, you replaced `user` with `user!` and you're getting the same error?

Comment: Yup. The error is pointing to linkUserInBackground, so I'm guessing it's the parameters that are off.

Comment: We need to find which parameters though! If you use `user!`, then the first parameter should be correct. Please confirm that the error message changes to not include the `PFUser?`. Then, for now, let's replace the `["email"]` with `nil` and see if that helps. The last step will be to leave the block parameter types in to help the type checker. I find that the easiest way to get this right is to delete my code and start over using autocomplete. This way I'm guaranteed to get all the types right.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me. I've tried to re-autocomplete this method. I've also tried to replace "withPermissions" with "permissions", and changed ["email"] to "nil". Also, autocomplete doesn't really give the right structure - it just gives parameters (user: PFUser, permission: [AnyObject]?).

Comment: That's helpful! Let's try without the block: `PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user!, permission: nil)`

Comment: The above method works - however, I want to include the success and error parts too to check for if it succeeded or not.

Comment: So what if you now do `PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user!, permission: nil) { success, error in //... }`

Comment: Error: "Extra argument 'permissions' in call

Comment: Where is `permissions`?

Comment: Sorry, added an extra 's' at the end. It goes back to "Cannot invoke 'linkUserInBackground'.......hmm.

Comment: Maybe try `PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user!, permission: nil, block: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in //... })` Also, maybe it has to do with the surrounding environment. Where is this method within the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 let permissions = ["email", "public_profile", "user_friends"]

    PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(currentUser.parseUser,withReadPermissions: permissions,block:{(succeeded: Bool, error: NSError? ) in

      if error != nil {
        print ("error in call to linkuser")
        return
      }

      if succeeded {
        print ("succeed to linkuser")
        self.linkWithFaceBookBtn.setTitle("Unlink your Account from Facebook", forState: .Normal)
      } else {
        print ("did not succedd to linkuser or user cancelled")
      }


  })
```